# Passing arguments to wp_list_comments callback function

Tags: comments, comments-template

One can customize single comment markup using the `callback` argument in `wp_list_comments` like this:

```
$args = array( 'callback' => 'my_callback', 'avatar_size' => 48, 'type' => 'comment' );
wp_list_comments( $args );
```

The question is, how to pass arguments to that `my_callback` function?
Already it gets three:

```
function my_callback( $comment, $args, $depth )
```

But I need to add my own 4th argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. you may simply add your arguments to the `wp_list_comments` as associative `key` => `value` pairs like this:

```
$args = array( 'callback' => 'my_callback', 'avatar_size' => 48, 'type' => 'comment', 'arg1' => $arg1 );
wp_list_comments( $args );
```

and then in your `my_callback` you have:

```
function my_callback( $comment, $args, $depth )
```

where you have access to `$arg1`;

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `use` in function:

```
function my_callback( $comment, $args, $depth ) use ( $my_arg1, $my_arg2, ... )
```

Comment: That doesn't work for named functions.